# How to call a context and return to the main context in asterisk?

Tags: asterisk

Here is my dial plan in asterisk:

```
[main-context]
exten => s,1,Gosub(subcontext,s,1)
exten => s,n,NoOp(End Main)

[subcontext]
exten => s,1,NoOp(Start subcontext)
exten => s,1,NoOp(End subcontext)
```

The problem is that when subcontext finishes, execution doesn't return to main-context and 
exten => s,n,NoOp(End Main) doesn't execute. How can I solve this?

Comment: Found the solution. At the end of subcontext I should add same=> n,Return()

Comment: That is the correct solution - feel free to answer your own question.

Comment: i don't have enough reputation to answer my own questions Matt. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Karadous posted above: a GoSub routine must have a matching Return() application call.

```
[main-context]
exten => s,1,Gosub(subcontext,s,1)
same => n,NoOp(End Main)

[subcontext]
exten => s,1,NoOp(Start subcontext)
same => n,NoOp(End subcontext)
same => n,Return()
```